# What will be happen after distributed cache enabled in Web font end servers

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, distributedcache

I have a 4 servers share point 2013 farm and in this 2 wfe servers,what will be happen after i enable distributed cache in two wfe servers and how distributed cache help to increase performance.

This farm host a public faced websites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Distributed cache provide a lot of advantages to SharePoint, as it cache the complex computational objects which SharePoint need all the time. following are the some of the things it did.

- cache newsfeeds,
- microblogging
- conversations
- security trimming and  OneNote client access
- cache stores your authentication token "Consider a lengthy process
  such as authentication in a federated identity scenario. A complex
  orchestration of network and service calls is required to
  authenticate a user and build a claims token for use in subsequent
  authorization operations. Caching such tokens in the Distributed
  Cache removes the need to constantly re-execute the sequence of
  (relatively slow) calls and can dramatically improve SharePoint
  performance.[Refer](http://www.karthikscorner.com/sharepoint/distributed-cache-service-in-sharepoint/)

Now running DC on the WFE, definitely give the better performance as authentication token stored in it. it cache frequently requested information and made it available quickly to all the servers(Web Front end) in the farm. it also help to reduce the traffic from SharePoint to SQL.

[AppFabric Caching and SharePoint: Concepts and Examples (Part 1)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/besidethepoint/2013/03/27/appfabric-caching-and-sharepoint-concepts-and-examples-part-1/)